# Python Pandas group based on column and get max, but exclude based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with some data and would like to pull the max for a certain column, grouped by a different column. However, I would like to exclude certain rows from the max calculation, based on another column.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
                   'Col2':['Build','Plan','Other','Test','Build','Other','Buy'],
                   'Col3':[2,5,17,5,13,12,12]})
```

I want to get the max of Col3, grouped by Col1, while excluding any rows that have 'Other' in Col2. Thus the max of Col3 for 'A' should be 5, not 17.

I was able to get the max of Col3 grouped by Col1 using: `df['new'] = df.groupby(['Col1'])['Col3'].transform(max)` However, this will give me a value of 17 for A.

From looking around in other threads, I tried using:

```
x = df1.groupby(['Col1'])
x2 = x.apply(lambda g: g[g['Col2'] != 'Other'])
```

and this seems to get me close (it has the data grouped by Col1 and has rows removed based on Col2). However, I cannot seem to find a way to get the max of Col3 based on Col1 anymore.

At best I have been able to use: `x2['Col3'].max()` to get the max of Col3 after removing all rows with 'Other' in Col2. However, I cannot get the max of Col3 grouped by Col1.

I was wondering if there was a way to use inbuilt Pandas functions to do this relatively simply, instead of creating a whole new bespoke function?

Comment: Filter your dataframe first then group by Col1.

Comment: df.query('Col2 != "Other"').groupby('Col1')['Col3'].max()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
df[df.Col2 != 'Other'].groupby('Col1').Col3.max()

Col1
A     5
B    13
```

To create a new column:

```
df['new']=df[df.Col2 != 'Other'].groupby('Col1').Col3.transform('max')
df['new'] = df.new.ffill()

    Col1    Col2    Col3    new
0   A       Build   2       5.0
1   A       Plan    5       5.0
2   A       Other   17      5.0
3   B       Test    5       13.0
4   B       Build   13      13.0
5   B       Other   12      13.0
6   B       Buy     12      13.0
```

Explanation: Select only the rows of the df where Col2 value are not equal to 'Other', groupby Col1, find max of Col3.

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) is the documentation of transform: 
It returns a like indexed df with transformed values rather than aggregating.

Comment: @Scott Boston, Infact I was wondering if I should post at all as you had already answered in the comment:)

Comment: @A-Za-z: never let people who should know better abusing the comment section prevent you from posting. ;-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that! Both of your answers worked :)

Would you know how to create a new column where I call that calculated max based on the value in Col1? Essentially making:

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
                   'Col2':['Build','Plan','Other','Test','Build','Other','Buy'],
                   'Col3':[2,5,17,5,13,12,12],
                   'new':[5,5,5,13,13,13,13]})

I have tried df['new'] = a[(df['Col1'])], but that doesn't seem to work. I get the following error: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: Thank you!! Worked perfectly :)

Comment: In the interest of learning your method, can you confirm if the logic goes like this? Create new dataframe where you exclude rows with 'Other' -> Group by Col1 -> within each Col1 Group get max of Col3. I never knew you could call transform max like that either.

Comment: @pyman, I have added some explanation. Also do accept the answer if it helped you. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to mix it up using `groupby`

```
df.groupby([df.Col2.ne('Other'), 'Col1']).Col3.max()[True]

Col1
A     5
B    13
Name: Col3, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Vaishali is a good start but I think it can have some problemes specially when applying ffill to get rid of na. 
For this method to work, you need your dataframe to be sorted in a particuler way. 
to be convinced, try this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B',"C", "C"],
               'Col2':['Build','Plan','Other','Test','Build','Other','Buy', "Buy","Other"],
               'Col3':[2,5,17,5,13,12,12,14,5]})
df = df.sample(frac=1) #shuffle rows

df['new']=df[df.Col2 != 'Other'].groupby('Col1')["Col3"].transform('max')
df['new'] = df.new.ffill()
```

And you can get this results which is not good.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    new
3   B   Test    5   13.0
7   C   Buy     14  14.0
6   B   Buy     12  13.0
1   A   Plan    5   5.0
0   A   Build   2   5.0
5   B   Other   12  5.0
8   C   Other   5   5.0
4   B   Build   13  13.0
2   A   Other   17  13.0
```

A better solution :
First define this function.

```
def new_transform(df, exclude_cond,gbycol,target, agg_fun, ignore_value=None):
    df['target_temp'] = df[target] 
    df.loc[eval(exclude_cond), 'target_temp'] = ignore_value
    tmp=df.groupby(gbycol)['target_temp'].transform(agg_fun)
    df.drop('target_temp', axis=1, inplace=True)
    return tmp
```

It will take your dataframe, your exculde_cond as string, your groupby as list of strings or a string, the target : column name on which we operate calculation, the aggregation function and a value ignored by the aggregation function (None will work for major agg functions).

Example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A','A','A','B','B','B','B',"C", "C"],
                   'Col2':['Build','Plan','Other','Test','Build','Other','Buy', "Buy","Other"],
                   'Col3':[2,5,17,5,13,12,12,14,5]})
df = df.sample(frac=1)
df['new']=new_transform(df, "df['Col2']=='Build'", ['Col1'],'Col3', 'sum', np.nan)
```

we get the right calculations :

```
  Col1  Col2    Col3    new
3   B   Test    5     29.0
2   A   Other   17    22.0
4   B   Build   13    29.0
6   B   Buy     12    29.0
7   C   Buy     14    19.0
1   A   Plan    5     22.0
5   B   Other   12    29.0
0   A   Build   2     22.0
8   C   Other   5     19.0
```